# Why would faker produce duplicate data?

Tags: node.js, random, lodash, seeding, faker

I'm using Faker in order to seed a database, I'm doing this using faker methods and `lodash#random`.

Data generation is inside a loop, but on every execution is producing whole duplicates, how can I avoid it?

```
faker.locale = "es";
var leagueTeams = [{ "name" : "Perú","id" : "t834"},{"name" : "Venezuela","id" : "t833"},{"name" : "Argentina","id" : "t632"},{"name" : "Uruguay","id" : "t837"},{"name" : "Colombia","id" : "t832"},{"name" : "Bolivia","id" : "t836"},{"name" : "Jamaica","id" : "t1723"},{"name" : "Brazil","id" : "t614"},{"name" : "Mexico","id" : "t659"},{"name" : "Ecuador","id" : "t830"},{"name" : "Chile","id" : "t831"},{"name" : "Paraguay","id" : "t835"}]


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var fakeName = faker.name.findName();
    var fakeEmail = faker.internet.email();
    var fakePassword = faker.internet.password();
    var fakeTeam = faker.hacker.phrase();
    var fakeTeamImage = faker.image.imageUrl();
    var fakeFavoriteTeam  = leagueTeams[_.random(0,11)];
    var fakeBirthday = faker.date.past();

    // Create account
    request.post(  {url:'http://localhost:1337/api/v1/auths/login',
                    form:   {
                                email: fakeEmail,
                                password: fakePassword,
                            }
                    },
                    function (err, httpResponse, body) {

                            body = JSON.parse(body);
                            var iduser = body.user.id;
                            var auth = "Bearer " + body.token;

                            // Create team

                            request.put({
                                            url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/v1/users/' + iduser,
                                            form: {
                                                    name: fakeName,
                                                    gender: ['male','female'][i%2],
                                                    team: {name: fakeTeam, image: fakeTeamImage},
                                                    fanOf: {
                                                        name: fakeFavoriteTeam.name,
                                                        id: fakeFavoriteTeam.id
                                                    },
                                                    birthDate: fakeBirthday,
                                                    iduser: iduser
                                            },
                                            headers: {"Authorization": auth}
                                        },
                                        function (err, httpResponse, body) {
                                            console.log(body);
                                        }
                            );
                    });
}
```

So whole faker methods like `faker.internet.findName()`, `faker.hacker.phrase()` or the statement using lodash `var fakeFavoriteTeam  = leagueTeams[_.random(0,11)];` is always producing the same result, how could I improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, The `var i` like statement within `for` loop was declare as global variable, and `request[method]` is not block code.
It mean it continues change unless there is no block code inside loop.

One way to declare local variable inside loop is using `let` (ES6 feature).

Example of using `let` in loop with none block code.

```
"use strict";
var peoples = [{name: "Person1"},{name: "Person2"}];
for(let person in people){
    let name = person.name;
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log(name) }, 1000);
}
```

However you have to run node using the optional --harmony flag.
Using "strict" mode is [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it).

OR You can simplely use `Array.prototype.map()` or `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Comment: You mean that by simply changing the `let` instead of `var` at the for loop it will improve the random generation?

Comment: As you code, you can replace `var fakeName, fakeEmail ....` to `let`. JS don't have local scope within loop statement, unlike `java` like language.

Comment: Can you edit your question telling details about getting ES6 support, the need of `"use strict"` and running node with `--harmony`